# Flutter: Create nested json array for country state and city selection

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, http-post

I have country, state and city dropdown in my flutter project. After selecting country/state/city I have to create a json array of selected and send it as json string in my backend api request payload.
JSON Array I required to create based on location selection to pass in api request is

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "stateCity": [
      {
        "state": "California",
        "city": [
          "Los Angeles",
          "City 2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "country": "India",
    "stateCity": [
      {
        "state": "Haryana",
        "city": [
          "Gurgaon",
          "Faridabad"
        ]
      },
      {
        "state": "Maharashtra"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "country": "Africa"
  }
]
```

**Scenarios are:**

1. If country does not exists in json array, create country object and add it to json array.
2. On selecting, state, check if state exists in json array, if yes then do nothing otherwise create a stateCity array with state and add it to the corresponding country object.
3. On selecting city, check if city exists in city list of stateCity object of selected country and state inside json array, if yes then do nothing, otherwise; if city parameter does not exists in stateCity Object then create one and add city to it and update main json array otherwise add selected city to city list then update the whole json array.

**Below code I have written:**

```
class StateCity {
  String? state;
  List<String?>? city;

  StateCity(this.state, this.city);
}

class Location {
  String country;
  List<StateCity?>? stateCity;

  Location(this.country, this.stateCity);
}

List<Location> loc = [];

void addLocation(String country, [String? state, String? city]) {
  state = state;
  city = city;
  
  Location? existingLocation;
  for (var location in loc) {
    if (location.country == country) {
      existingLocation = location;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (existingLocation == null) {
    var newLocation = Location(country, []);
    
    if (state != null && city != null) {
      var newStateCity = StateCity(state, [city]);
      newLocation.stateCity!.add(newStateCity);
    }
    
    loc.add(newLocation);
  } else {
    if (state != null && city != null) {
      StateCity? existingStateCity;
      for (var sc in existingLocation.stateCity!) {
        if (sc!.state == state) {
          existingStateCity = sc;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (existingStateCity == null) {
        var newStateCity = StateCity(state, [city]);
        existingLocation.stateCity!.add(newStateCity);
      } else {
        if (existingStateCity.city!.isEmpty) {
          existingStateCity.city = [city];
        } else if (!existingStateCity.city!.contains(city)) {
          existingStateCity.city!.add(city);
        }
      }
    } else if (state != null) {
      var existingStateCity = existingLocation.stateCity!.firstWhere((sc) => sc!.state == state, orElse: () => null);
      
      if (existingStateCity == null) {
        var newStateCity = StateCity(state, []);
        existingLocation.stateCity!.add(newStateCity);
      }
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  addLocation('united states', 'california', 'los angeles');
  addLocation('united states', 'california', 'city 2');
  addLocation('india', 'maharashtra');
  addLocation('africa');

}
```

When printing the loc it is not showing in json array format and also not showing it in json array string to pass it in request
Eg.

```
    '[{
"country":"United States",
"stateCity":[{

    "state":"California",
    "city":["Los Angeles","City 2"]} 

    ]}]'
```